# TableViewController UISearchBar after rotation cancel button not clickable

Tags: ios, ios6, rotation, uisearchbar

I got a TableVieController with a searchBar positioned at *self.tableView.tableHeaderView* . When the screen rotates I am just setting the frame to the new CGRect. The view looks alright but unfortunately half of the search bar isn't clickable, neither is the cancel button.

So how do I make this work? I only managed to do it by creating a new instance of the search bar and assign it, but that won't be the right way, right?

```
const CGRect CGRECT_TABLE_VIEW_PORTRAIT = { { 0.0f, 0.0f }, { 320.0f, 365.0f } };
const CGRect CGRECT_TABLE_VIEW_LANDSCAPE = { { 0.0f, 0.0f }, { 480.0f, 150.0f } };


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
... 
        // create search bar
        searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:self.tableView.bounds];
        [searchBar setTintColor:RGB(168, 212, 255)] ;    
        searchBar.showsCancelButton = YES;
        [searchBar sizeToFit]; // Get the default height for a search bar.
        searchBar.delegate = self;

        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar;
        self.tableView.frame = CGRECT_TABLE_VIEW_PORTRAIT;
}


- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)
interfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {

        if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation)) {
              tableView.frame = CGRECT_TABLE_VIEW_LANDSCAPE;
        } else {
              tableView.frame = CGRECT_TABLE_VIEW_LANDSCAPE;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you're trying to deal with rotations, when this should happen automatically. This code worked to give a search bar that adjusts itself on rotation:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    UISearchBar *searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:self.tableView.bounds];
    [searchBar setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:168/255 green:212/255 blue:1 alpha:1]];
    searchBar.showsCancelButton = YES;
    [searchBar sizeToFit]; // Get the default height for a search bar.
    searchBar.delegate = self;
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar;
}
```

Comment: Hi, so you mean I don't have to implement willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation... ? But if I don't the search bar still is 320px wide (and not 480). If I set it in the rotation method the search bar + plus the cancel button is 480px wide (OK) but the clickable area within the searchbar + button ends after 320px. I don't seem to find an answer to that :(

Comment: @jeven, I don't know why you see that behavior. In my test app, I added a table view controller in the storyboard, and added just the code I posted -- that worked fine to handle the rotations. Did you try the above code alone?

Comment: Interesting: I am using an UIViewController (not an UITableViewController) initializing it with a nib that contains a tableView which I connect to a member (uiViewController.tableView). I am using not a tableViewController cause I need to add advertisement views to it. I just changed my code and initialized the controller without a nib, and as you said rotating comes out of the box... guess I missed sth in the nib file huh?!